# one to one parent child relationship sql server

Tags: sql-server, parent-child

I have a table with fields `TransactionID`, `Amount` and `ParentTransactionID`
The transactions can be cancelled so a new entry posted with `amount` and `ParentTransactionID` as cancelled `TransactionID`.

Lets say a transaction

> 1 100 NULL

I cancelled the above entry, it will like

> 2 -100 1

Again cancelled the above transaction, so it should like

> 3 100 2

When I fetch  I should get the record 3 as ID 1 and 2 got cancelled.
result should be

> 3 100 2

If I cancelled the 3rd entry no records should return.

```
SELECT * FROM Transaction t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 NULL FROM Transaction pt
WHERE (pt.ParentTransactionID = t.TransactionID OR t.ParentTransactionID = pt.TransactionID)
AND ABS(t.Amount) = ABS(pt.Amount))
```

This works if only one level of cancel is made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all transactions are cancelled by a new transaction setting ParentTransactionId to the transaction it cancels, it can be done using a simple `LEFT JOIN`;

```
SELECT t1.* FROM Transactions t1
LEFT JOIN Transactions t2
  ON t1.TransactionId = t2.ParentTransactionId
WHERE t2.TransactionId IS NULL;
```

`t1` being the transaction we're currently looking at and `t2` being the possibly cancelling transaction. If there is no cancelling transaction (ie the `TransactionId` for `t2` does not exist), return the row.

I'm not sure about your last statement though, `If I cancelled the 3rd entry no records should return.`. How would you cancel #3 without adding a new transaction to the table? You may have some other condition for a cancel you're not telling us about...?

[Simple SQLfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c6693/2).

EDIT: Since you don't want cancelled transactions (or rather transactions with an odd number of cancellations), you need a quite a bit more complicated recursive query to figure out whether to show the last transaction or not;

```
WITH ChangeLog(TransactionID, Amount, ParentTransactionID, 
               IsCancel, OriginalTransactionID) AS
(
  SELECT TransactionID, Amount, ParentTransactionID, 0, TransactionID
  FROM Transactions WHERE ParentTransactionID IS NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t.TransactionID, t.Amount, t.ParentTransactionID, 
         1-c.IsCancel, c.OriginalTransactionID
  FROM Transactions t
  JOIN ChangeLog c ON c.TransactionID = t.ParentTransactionID
) 
SELECT c1.TransactionID, c1.Amount, c1.ParentTransactionID
FROM ChangeLog c1
LEFT JOIN ChangeLog c2
  ON c1.TransactionID < c2.TransactionID
     AND c1.OriginalTransactionID = c2.OriginalTransactionID
WHERE c2.TransactionID IS NULL AND c1.IsCancel=0
```

This will, in your example with 3 transactions, show the last row, but if the last row is cancelled, it won't return anything.

Since SQLfiddle is up again, [here is a fiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9c5b3/4).

A short explanation of the query may be in order even if a bit hard to do in a simple way; it defines a recursive "view", `ChangeLog` that tracks cancels and the original transaction id from the original to the last transaction in a series (a series is all transactions with the same OriginalTransactionId). After that, it joins `ChangeLog` with itself to find the last entry (ie all transactions that don't have a cancelling transaction). If the last entry found in a series is not a cancel (`IsCancel`=0) it will show up.

Comment: Thanks,,  
If I cancelled the the 3rd one a new transaction will be made with
TransactionID : 4 Amount : -100  ParentTransactionID : 3
The above query result the last entry..

In this case no row should return as all the transactions got cancelled.

Comment: @user1204716 So how do I know it's cancelled? It's the reverse amount of the first transaction, or are you thinking some other way?

Comment: If a transaction is cancelled then a new entry is made. 
The parenttransactionid of the new transaction is the transactionid of the cancelled.

Comment: @user1204716 What I'm trying to get to is; why would your existing example return the third entry (the original transaction has been cancelled in both cases), while an additional cancel would result in _no_ entries returned? Or am I misunderstanding something completely?

Comment: I donot want to show the cancelled transactions.
I made a transaction(1) and I cancelled it(2). So I donot want to show both transactions.

If I again cancelled the transaction(2) (Cancelled Transaction), I need to show the new transaction(3) (Cancelled Cancelled). Then only it matched with the total.

If I cancel the 3rd One, 4th transaction is made, so no need to show any.

Comment: @user1204716 Edited with a query that will do what I believe you want.